# Throttled event callbacks in React cause error after component is unmounted

Tags: reactjs

I have a window resize event callback that I decided to throttle to improve performance. At certain breakpoints, the component is removed. The result is that sometimes when resizing, I get this message: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findDOMNode was called on an unmounted component.`

When I remove the throttle, this error goes away. I think what's happening is the following sequence:

1. Resize event fires and calls `throttle`
2. The component is unmounted
3. `throttle` calls `_updateInstance`.

I can easily solve this by checking if the component is mounted inside `_updateInstance`, but the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) seem to argue that doing this is always a code smell. I understand their reasons, but I think that what I'm doing is fine and they don't mention this case.

I'm wondering if there's a more appropriate way to do what I'm doing and avoid the `Invariant Violation`. Right now I'm setting an `isMounted` flag, but a) it's annoying, and b) it would hide the error message in all cases, even when it might indicate an actual problem (as detailed in the docs I linked to above).

Here's the relevant code. BTW, the error is being thrown from the first line of `_updateInstance`.

```
constructor() {
  this._handleScreenChange = throttle(this._updateInstance.bind(this), 250);
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this._handleScreenChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this._handleScreenChange);
}

_updateInstance() {
  const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
  if (!inViewport(el)) return;
  this.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: react components do not have an api to handle async actions. Anything ajax/throttled/debounce/etc is best handled outside of the component because of this exact situation. modern throttle/debounce functions provide a way to cancel the call. https://github.com/lodash/lodash/commit/11d131839f17e32c6dc45bd26d6061bad6633295 i would recommend using current lodash implementation of of debounce/throttle and cancel on `componentWillUnmount`